# Upgrading vers 9 to 10, confused on last step of official documentation article "Manually upgrade a project to Sitefinity CMS 10.0 with a NuGet pack"

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am following the documentation listed below:

https://docs.sitefinity.com/apply-authentication-model-after-nuget-package-upgrade

The last step, number 8 says,

"Copy the new ResourcePackages folder.  
If you have changes in the folder, be careful not to overwrite them."

**Question:** Where am I suppose to get/copy the "new ResourcePackages" from and where do I copy it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a support ticket with Sitefinity, in short, the solution is when upgrading using Nuget you must respond "Yes/Yes to All" when asked to overwrite the following:

"File 'ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\razorgenerator.directives' already exists in project 'SitefinityWebApp'. Do you want to overwrite it? [Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [?] Help (default is "N"):"

**Below is the full response from Sitefinity**

> I can see the confusion in the wording, as it took myself some time to understand this step. This step in my opinion should be apart of the following documentation :
>
> https://docs.sitefinity.com/upgrade-a-project-that-has-nuget-packages
>
> During the NuGet upgrade, the Package Manager Console will prompt you with the following :
>
> "File 'ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\razorgenerator.directives' already exists in project 'SitefinityWebApp'. Do you want to overwrite it?
>   [Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [?] Help (default is "N"):"
>
> Which refers to the "Copy the new ResourcePackages folder." line.
>
> The second line :
>
> "If you have changes in the folder, be careful not to overwrite them."
>
> Is a caution, mentioning that, if you do have custom changes in your ResourcePackages folder, be careful not to overwrite those changes, as selecting "Yes/Yes to All" will do so.
>
> I hope my response clarifies any confusion. Please let me know if you have any further questions.
>
> Regards,
>   Wesley Skiba
>
> Support Engineer:  Wieslaw Skiba
>
> Thank you,
>   Wieslaw Skiba

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean is this:
it is almost always expected that you do not use the built-in Bootstrap package, but rather a copy of it, e.g. a custom package called MyClientNamePackage.

Now, the upgrade procedure will update the Bootstrap resource package folder (it asks if you want to override the files) but then it is up to you to manually copy the updated bootstrap folder onto your custom package folder.

Answer (score 0):

I though Nuget will install the latest resource packages folder, but if it's written in their docs.

You can copy Resource packages from Project Manager installation:

1. Download and install Sitefinity CMS Project Manager
2. Create ***dummy*** project in this manager
3. Copy `{ProjectManagerInstallationPath}\_EmptyProject\ResourcePackages` to your project `{YourProjectPath}\ResourcePackages`